# html disabled textfield should allow changes made by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a textfield which should be disabled for user-actions but should be filled by a javascript after another user-action. Is this somehow possible?

It can be a solution made by js, css or even html.

Comment: add `disabled` attribute to the input and update its value via js

Comment: what you tried? show some code ;)

Comment: sorry, its to early this morning ;). 

I'll update it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field

```
<input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" readonly>
```

`readonly` mean the value is not null and the field not changeable. Whereas`disabled` might causing the `input` value being null.

And your javascript is like this

```
function changeVal(myval){
     document.getElementById('text1').value = myval;
}
```

Complete Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yuk0mcrx/

Answer (score 2):

Without some code to illustrate your situation it's difficult to say for sure, but something like this might suffice:

```js
function updateTextbox() {
  document.getElementById('text').value = 'Value updated through JavaScript'
}
```

```html
<input id="text" type="text" disabled="disabled"  />

<button id="update" onclick="updateTextbox()">Update Textbox</button>
```

Adding `disabled="disabled"` to your input will disable it from user input, but can still be changed through javascript.

EDIT: If you want to change the value through a click on the element (as suggested in comments) this is a little more difficult as elements do not trigger click events when disabled. We can however use an invisible element in front of the input as a work-around:

```js
function update() {
  document.getElementById('textbox').value="Updated from hidden element click!"
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative;">
  <input type="text" id = "textbox" disabled="disabled" style="width: 250px; height: 20px;"/>

  <!-- You'll need to account for default border/padding on input elements when styling -->
  <div onclick="update()" id="invisible" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; height: 26px; width: 254px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks pretty nice. Is it even possible to fill the textfield with a click on that disabled-textfield? Shouldnt be problem of java, should it?

Comment: That's a bit more difficult, as disabled elements don't fire click-events, but it could be done by placing an 'invisible' element in front of the input and picking up a click on that instead. I will add this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input id="myText" type="text" value="Hello">
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("myText").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("myText").value = "Yes, Changed!";
```

In JS you can make whatever changes you want to make and you can trigger it on any user action.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/5cj0sb74/)**